# RecursiveIteratorIterator callHasChildren() returning always true

Tags: php, iterator

I would like to use the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` class to build a menu.

Actually I'm using `Zend_Navigation` container to build main menu and breadcrumbs, however it doesn't suit my other needs, so I'm using container with iterator:

```
$navigation = $this->view->navigation()->getContainer();
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $navigation,
RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
```

Then I like to know, two things - current level and if item has more children.
First one can I achieve by `getDepth()` method and for second one I tried to use 
`callHasChildren()`, but this one is always returning TRUE, even if item has not more children.

```
foreach ($iterator as $page) {         
    echo $iterator->getDepth() . $iterator->callHasChildren()) . '<br />';
}
```

Any idea how to use this method?

Comment: Try doing a var_dump on `$this->view->navigation()` likely it is an array like object with other public properties.  You might be able to create the iterator with `$navigation->toArray();`

Comment: Hello, unfortunately I'm not sure how this can help me. Navigation array is not containing property to get depth and also is not containing direct info about children. I'm currently using count($pages)  to get correct number, but this can be consider as workaround in this case.

Comment: echo $iterator->getDepth() . count($page->getPages()) . '<br />';